# Properly calling a body onload event handler in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

My doOnLoad function is not running when page is loaded. Any idea what is wrong with my code?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/events.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {



    //Not working. How do I get this function to run when the body is loaded?
    $("body").load(function() {
        doOnLoad();
    });


        //doOnChange is running properly
    $('#mydirection').change(function() {
        doOnChange();
    })

});
</script>
```

Comment: Why would use something like this, get rid of it!

Answer (score 1):

From http://api.jquery.com/ready/:

> The `.ready()` method is generally incompatible with the `<body onload="">` attribute. If `load` must be used, either do not use `.ready()` or use jQuery's `.load()` method to attach `load` event handlers to the window or to more specific items, like images.

Comment: Perfect, I just called doOnLoad(); instead of:

 $("body").load(function() {
  doOnLoad();
 });

Thanks for helping a newbie :)

Comment: $(window).load(function() {
  doOnLoad();
 });

Comment: To be sure, just using the `ready` handler instead of `load` is typically the way to go. If you don't need to wait for the page to be fully rendered (the DOM construction is enough), you can just call `doOnLoad()` after the first four lines. Have fun!